# computing the cubed root of a complex number...

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I do know how to calculate the cubed root of a complex number....like if I'm given that $x^3=p$, where $p$ is a complex number, then $$x= r^{1/3}\left(\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi+m}{3}\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{2k\pi+m}{3}\right)\right)$$ where $p$ is $r\left(\cos m +i\sin m\right)$ and $k=0,1,2$

But can I write it in this way??
$$x^3=p \implies x=p^{1/3},\,p^{1/3}w , \,p^{1/3} w^2, \dots$$
where $w$ is the cubed root of unity?
I thought that if I write the roots in this way and put any value of $p^{1/3}$, I get all the three values of $x$ what I got using the first method...thanks

Comment: The trouble with your idea is that to get off the ground you first have to know what $p^{1/3}$ is, which brings you back to where you began.

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE. Please learn to use formatting so that your question becomes more readable

Comment: Gerry Myerson ....sir...I think If I take any value of p^1/3 in place of that form.....then I always get the three values of x.....I don't know exactly but...still...I am not right...yeah?

Comment: You can take one value for the cubed root, call it the *principle* cubed root, and then the others will be off by a power of a cubed root of unity. And they would exactly be the same as the values from the first method.

Comment: Sorry, principal, not principle

Comment: Yes, but to take a value of $p^{1/3}$ means to write something like the $r^{1/3}(\cos(m/3)+i\sin(m/3))$ that you seem to want to avoid. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment directed to me, it's not enough to include my name. You have to use an at-sign: @Gerry.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$x^3-a=(x-a^{1/3})(x^2+xa^{1/3}+a^{2/3})$$